# How to send wishlist frontend view via email to currently login customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, wishlist

I want to send `wishlist` frontend view to currently login customer through email.

In detail, there will be button `send wishlist`,  after clicking on that button current logged-in customers automatically receives email with wishlist frontend details.

if information can be as `pdf` attachment then it will be better.

Comment: @Jai do you have any idea regarding this? after checking your profile i know that you are magento developer. if yes please help

Comment: Sorry dear, its long time that I worked in Magento 1.9.